# How to retrieve value from one to one field tables in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have used two models and a django built in User model.

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    user_contact = models.CharField()
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('exam.UserInfo')
    is_reviewed= models.BooleanField()
```

The `UserInfo` field is one to one with the `User` model. User model have the `'username'` field that I want to retrieve. But I can't get through how to get the `username` of those users who have `is_reviewed` field is `0`. So far what I was trying but failed to retrieve:

```
result=Review.objects.select_related('user_id__id').filter(is_reviewed=0)
```

Comment: Since `is_reviewed` is a boolean, shouldn't the filter be `is_reviewed=False`?

Comment: @JonKiparsky: actually in most databases, `0` and `False` are the same thing.

Comment: Understood, and in python False == 0, but this is a question of writing decent code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need `select_related`, that's a performance tuning tool. If you want `Review` model instances, just make your query and retrieve related values from that as normal:

```
result = Review.objects.filter(is_reviewed=False)
```

Then the name is available with dotted lookups, eg:

```
result[0].user.user.username
```

These will make further queries - `select_related` helps you tune whether or not to prefetch those.

If you just want the usernames, you can use a `values` or `values_list` query, eg:

```
usernames = Review.objects.filter(is_reviewed=False).values_list('user__user__username', flat=True)
```